# Can I pass the knife.rb to the knife command as an argument?

Tags: windows, chef-infra, knife

chef-client v12.15.19 (MSI installer)
On Windows Server 2012 R2

Instead of having to be in the directory where knife.rb is located or put knife.rb in one of the pre-determined locations where knife looks for that config, can I just pass it in as an argument?

Example: `knife.bat node list -config_file c:\some\other\place\knife.rb`

I'm just curious if this is possible because I didn't see this anywhere in the docs. I know I could workaround this with an environment variable and possibly other ways, but I just was wondering if there was an arg to pass the knife.rb directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a different configuration file. Here's a snip of the `knife --help` output from the latest Chef 12.x releases (at the time of this writing):

```
 -c, --config CONFIG              The configuration file to use
     --config-option OPTION=VALUE Override a single configuration option
```

So you should be able to do `knife -c ...`. I use this regularly to manage different knife configuration files for different hosted chef instances. I don't see it mentioned in any docs explicitly either.

Comment: can you pass knife a pem file too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify but mind the parameters sequence.

```
knife cookbook upload my_test_cookbook -c ./knife.rb
```

You can specify options only after your main command is complete. 
The same you can check in knife help :
**Usage: knife sub-command (options)**